# Volley Error: Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, android-volley

I am working with my code and I get this error when I am trying to send my parameters to the server.

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Then I tried to add Looper.prepare() to the code and now the app crashes when I hit the button. I am using a QR reader to get the textview that I then send back to the server for certain parts then there is other parts of my program. This is just the part when I send the data. I also am getting location and using spinners and an edittext field.

Here is my code...

```
 send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

 Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "Make it work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // Intent meow = new Intent(QRCODEPAGE1.this, QRLASTPAGE.class);
           // startActivity(meow);

            Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "Started", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RequestQueue mRequestQueue = 
 Volley.newRequestQueue(QRCODEPAGE1.this);
            String url = "http://api- 
 dev.eportfolioapi.com/api/sensor/install";
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024*1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            //Looper.prepare();
            //mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "DONE", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
  url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
  Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "you passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
 //Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "you failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, String.valueOf(error), 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Volley ERROR: ", error.toString());
        //Looper.prepare();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "Params", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("userId", tvresult.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "you passed userid", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put("customerId", custID.toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "you passed custid", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put("sensorId", tvresult.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "sensorid", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         params.put("projectId", tvresult.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "you passed proid", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put("sensorVendorID", tvresult.getText().toString());
        params.put("sensorGatewayId", tvresult.getText().toString());
       // params.put("qrCodeUrl", );
        params.put("lat", textLat.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "lat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put("long", textLong.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(QRCODEPAGE1.this, "long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put("locationWithinFacility", descprit.getText().toString());
        return params;

    }
};


            request.setTag(TAG);
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
```

Where should I add that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of a *Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()* exception is trying to do something related to the UI from a background thread.

In your case you should not display toasts in the `getParams()` method as it probably called from a Volley worker thread

Answer (score 0):

onResponse and onErrorResponse are executed outside UI thread.